# Azure DevOps | E265 block comment should start with '# ' (linting)

Tags: github, azure-devops, lint, azure-pipelines-build-task, cicd

I cannot see what the error is here. I only think these are Warnings.

**What is there error message, and a probable cause?**

Update: I ran linting in **VS Code** using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`: `>Python: Run Linting`. Pushed changes and ran the pipeline again.

---

`test_ontology_tagger.py`:

```py
import pathlib

import pytest
# from dagster import execute_solid
# from ontology_tagger.ontology_tagger_worker import batch_predict
# from pwmf.pipeline.utils import local_mode
import yaml
# from pycm import ConfusionMatrix
import pandas as pd
# import datetime

from ontology_tagger.modules.s3_util import S3Util

import os
import logging

cwd = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
s3_util = S3Util()


@pytest.fixture
def models_with_unit_test_data():
    return models('data_local')


@pytest.fixture
def models_with_functional_test_data():
    return models('functional_test')


def models(test_file):
    try:
        with open(cwd.parent / 'models.yaml') as fh:
            models = yaml.safe_load(fh)
            model_test_data = {}
            for model, meta in models.items():
                if meta['test']['skip_unit_test']:
                    continue
                if test_file in meta['test']:
                    model_test_data[model] = meta['test'][test_file]
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Cannot load models.yaml {e}')
    return model_test_data


@pytest.fixture
def s3_paths():
    try:
        with open(cwd.parent / 'models.yaml') as fh:
            models = yaml.safe_load(fh)
            model_validation_results = {}
            for model, meta in models.items():
                path = meta['local']['model_s3'].split('.')[0]
                model_validation_results[model] = path
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Cannot load models.yaml {e}')
    return model_validation_results


def get_config(test_file='../data/test.csv', remove_ids=False):

    if remove_ids:
        df = pd.read_csv(test_file, header=None, sep='\t', index_col=0)
        test_data = (cwd / 'temp.csv').as_posix()
        print(f'Removing ids and generating test file in {test_data}')
        df.to_csv(test_data, header=False, index=False, sep='\t')
    else:
        test_data = (cwd / test_file).as_posix()

    return {
        'resources': {
            'fqdn_string': {'config': {'fqdn': None}},
            'mds_store': {
                'config': {
                    'mds_uri': 'mongodb://root:broot@localhost:27017/mds?authSource=admin'
                }
            },
            'file_cache': {'config': {'target_folder': './'}},
            'file_manager': {'config': {}},
            's3': {},
        },
        'solids': {
            'batch_predict': {
                'inputs': {
                    'batch_size': {'value': 20},
                    'data_uri': {'value': test_data},
                    's3_uri': {'value': 'dbpedia_comprehensive'},
                    'instance_type': {'value': 'local'},
                    'batch_id': {'value': ''},
                }
            }
        },
    }


'''
@pytest.mark.unit
def test_batch_predict_local(models_with_unit_test_data):
    for model, test_data_path in models_with_unit_test_data.items():
        config = get_config('../' + test_data_path)
        config['solids']['batch_predict']['inputs']['s3_uri']['value'] = model
        dataset = config['solids']['batch_predict']['inputs']['data_uri']['value']
        print(f'testing model {model} on data {dataset}')
        output = execute_solid(batch_predict, run_config=config, mode_def=local_mode)
        assert output.success is True
        assert 'predictions' in output.output_values
        assert 'id' in output.output_values['predictions']
        assert 'probabilities' in output.output_values['predictions']
        assert 'classes' in output.output_values['predictions']

        cl = output.output_values['predictions']['classes']
        lb = output.output_values['predictions']['id']

        n_cl = len(cl[0])
        n_lb = len(lb[0])
        assert n_cl == n_lb
        for i in range(n_cl):
            accuracy = sum(1 for x, y in zip(cl, lb) if x[i] == y[i]) / float(len(cl))
            assert accuracy > 0.70


@pytest.mark.unit
def test_generate_performance_metrics(models_with_functional_test_data, s3_paths):
    """
    save metric files to s3 under the same s3 path as the model names in models.yaml
    """
    timestamp_folder = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    for model, test_data_path in models_with_functional_test_data.items():
        config = get_config(test_data_path, remove_ids=True)
        config['solids']['batch_predict']['inputs']['s3_uri']['value'] = model
        dataset = config['solids']['batch_predict']['inputs']['data_uri']['value']
        print(f'testing model {model} on data {dataset}')
        output = execute_solid(batch_predict, run_config=config, mode_def=local_mode)
        cl = output.output_values['predictions']['classes']
        lb = output.output_values['predictions']['id']
        s3_path = s3_paths[model]
        n = len(cl[0])
        classes = []
        labels = []
        for i in range(n):
            for c, l in zip(cl, lb):
                try:
                    c_t = c[i]
                    l_t = l[i]
                    append = True
                except IndexError:
                    print(f'skipping {c} and {l} for class {i}')
                    append = False
                if append:
                    classes.append(c_t)
                    labels.append(l_t)
            cm = ConfusionMatrix(actual_vector=labels, predict_vector=classes)
            out_file = f'confusion_matrix_class{i+1}'
            print(f'Uploading metrics for file {out_file} to {s3_path}')
            cm.save_html(out_file)
            s3_util.upload_file(
                f'{out_file}.html', f'{s3_path}/{timestamp_folder}/{out_file}.html'
            )
            cm.save_csv(out_file)
            s3_util.upload_file(
                f'{out_file}.csv', f'{s3_path}/{timestamp_folder}/{out_file}.csv'
            )
'''


@pytest.mark.unit
def test_validation_classifier_dataset(models_with_unit_test_data):  # might do both ClassifierDataset and LabelMapper
    for model, test_data_path in models_with_unit_test_data.items():
        config = get_config('../' + test_data_path)
        config['solids']['batch_predict']['inputs']['s3_uri']['value'] = model
        dataset = config['solids']['batch_predict']['inputs']['data_uri']['value']
        print(f'testing model {model} on data {dataset}')

        validation_log_init()

        # ...

        num_lines = validation_log_init()
        assert num_lines == 2  # no. lines in log file expected


"""
@pytest.mark.unit
def test_validation_label_mapper(models_with_unit_test_data):
    for model, test_data_path in models_with_unit_test_data.items():
        config = get_config('../' + test_data_path)
        config['solids']['batch_predict']['inputs']['s3_uri']['value'] = model
        dataset = config['solids']['batch_predict']['inputs']['data_uri']['value']
        print(f'testing model {model} on data {dataset}')

        validation_log_init()

        # ...

        num_lines = validation_log_init()
        assert num_lines == 1  # no. lines in log file expected
"""


@pytest.fixture
def validation_log_init():
    global log_file
    log_file = 'test_ontology_tagger.log'
    open(log_file, 'w').close()  # empties file
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file, level=logging.INFO)


@pytest.fixture
def validation_log_check_clear():
    size = os.path.getsize(log_file)
    os.remove(log_file)  # 'global log_file'
    return size
```

Build Traceback:

```sh
#17 5.630             print(f'testing model {model} on data {dataset}')
#17 5.630     
#17 5.630 >           validation_log_init()
#17 5.630 
#17 5.630 tests/test_ontology_tagger.py:174: 
#17 5.631 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
#17 5.631 
#17 5.631     @pytest.fixture
#17 5.631     def validation_log_init():
#17 5.631         global log_file
#17 5.631         log_file = '../notebooks/test_ontology_tagger.log'
#17 5.631 >       open(log_file, 'w').close()  # empties file
#17 5.631 E       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../notebooks/test_ontology_tagger.log'
#17 5.631 
#17 5.631 tests/test_ontology_tagger.py:204: FileNotFoundError
#17 5.632 =============================== warnings summary ===============================
#17 5.632 ontology_tagger/tests/test_ontology_tagger.py::test_validation_classifier_dataset
#17 5.632   /home/worker/python/ontology_tagger/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:166: RemovedInPytest4Warning: Fixture "validation_log_init" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly, are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters. See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html for more information.
#17 5.632     testfunction(**testargs)
#17 5.632 
#17 5.632 -- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
#17 5.633 ===================== 1 failed, 1 warnings in 2.36 seconds =====================
#17 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd ontology_tagger && poetry run invoke deploy]: exit code: 1
------
 > [test 5/5] RUN cd ontology_tagger && poetry run invoke deploy:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd ontology_tagger && poetry run invoke deploy]: exit code: 1
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Test worker
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

Comment: The linter is telling you what the problems are and how to fix them.

Comment: You probably want to set the option to not fail on exit code.

Comment: @jessehouwing How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linter package I was using is `flake8`.

This was a series of code quality problems.

---

The last one being `E265 block comment should start with '# '`.

This meant that a space   had to appear immediately after `#`; before any and all other text.

```py
#This comment needs a space
def print_name(self):
    print(self.name)
```

```py
# Comment is correct now
def print_name(self):
    print(self.name)
```

[Source](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E265.html)